# What is the regex for date type

Tags: java, regex, string

I have one string I want to find out all date values and relace them with specific string.

My code looks like:

```
String mydata = "{[... \"date\":\"2016-03-16T12:38:28.390Z\"]},{[ ... \"date\":\"2016-03-16T12:38:28.390Z\" ...]}";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
        while(matcher.find()){
            mydata = mydata.replace(matcher.group(), matcher.group().substring(0, 10));
        }
        System.out.println(mydata);
```

What string regex I should pass in `Pattern.compile("");`?

My output should look like:

```
{[... "date":"2016-03-16"]},{[ ... "date":"2016-03-16" ...]}
```

Comment: It lloks like json data. So you should use a json Parser not regex

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.json.*;


JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{[... "date":"2016-03-16"]},{[ ... "date":"2016-03-16" ...]}");
```

The rest of the code depends on your json-structure. Have a look at:

[How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

or

[Java Api Link JsonObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about `T` and `Z` from input. If they are same always, then below regex will work. If `T` and `Z` not constant then change `T` and `Z` by `[A-Z]` in regex.

one more change i did, replaced

`mydata = mydata.replace(matcher.group(), matcher.group().substring(0, 10));`

by

```
mydata = matcher.replaceAll("");
```

It getting required output.

```
String mydata = "{[\"date\":\"2016-03-16T12:38:28.390Z\"]},{[\"date\":\"2016-03-16T12:38:28.390Z\"]}";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("T\\d{2}\\:\\d{2}\\:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}Z");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
while(matcher.find()){
   mydata = matcher.replaceAll("");
}
System.out.println(mydata);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `regex` based solution this seems to work for your example

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\{\\[.*?\"date\":\"\\d{4}\\-\\d{2}\\-\\d{2}).*?(\"\\]\\})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);

while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(2));
}
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/Wvccpm)**